# Preserving Lne breaks in HTML Table content

Tags: html

I have a table that displays contents which can be edited. Users can insert line breaks and this has to be reflected in the table (i.e the line breaks should be preserved.). I used `white-space:preline`  which works for IE-8, FF, etc.. but in IE-7, the line breaks are not shown. I tried using `word-wrap:break-word` but still it doesnt work for me...

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you really need to be more specific or post ur code

Comment: i just want the contents of a particular <TD> in a table to preserve line breaks..I have been able to do this in Firefox, IE-8, Chrome, etc. But for IE-7, no line-breaks/new line gets displayed. All the words in a text come together.e.g "Hi, My name is XYZ.Thank you for your valueable feedback.SincerelyXYZ"..but in other browsers, it appears formatted, i.e after Hi, there is a new line. After Sincerely, there is a new line..

Answer (score 0):

[This table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) would suggest `whitespace:pre` is more widely supported than `white-space:preline`. If you don't mind the preservation of other whitespace (tabs, multiple spaces etc.), you could try using that.

Comment: with <pre>, my page expands and scrolls horizontally which i dont want.